Does the Firestore write batch limit of 500 operations still exist?
The Firestore write batch documentation says there is a 500 operations limit.
However, the Firestore release notes say this limit has been removed in March 2023.
Which one should I believe?

Consider using the "send feedback" button at the top of every page of Firebase documentation to raise these sorts of issues.

@Doug Stevenson, I just sent the feedback.

Most likely the official documentation regarding batched writes is outdated. You can add more than 500 operations to a batch. So the release notes from March 2023 are correct. Besides that, I did not find such a limitation inside the Firestore usage and limis.
Finally, to be absolutely sure, I personally tested and I was able to add more than 500 operations to a batch, and the batch operation ended successfully.

Important note, as indicated in the docs is that even if the 500 operations is no longer applicable there is still a limit for transaction size of 10 MiB which may result in batch write failures
